# data is not persisting to database and showing a null pointer exception in console

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i am a beginner to spring boot and I am performing a CRUD operation on database using spring boot .the program complies with no error but during running my application i encounter an error: `NullPointerException`.

this is my program:-

CrudOperationApplication.java

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CrudOperationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudOperationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DatabaseCon.java

```
package com;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@ComponentScan({ "com" })
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DatabaseCon {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com" });
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return sessionFactory;
         }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }

        private Properties hibernateProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
            properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
            return properties;       
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
           HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
           txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
           return txManager;
        }
    }
```

Employee.java

```
package com;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="salary")
    int salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }


}
```

EmployeeDao.java

```
package com;

public interface EmployeeDao {

    String insertValue(Employee e);
    String updateValue(Employee e);
    String deleteValue(Employee e);
    String getValue();
    String getSpecificValue( int id);
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
package com;

import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController implements EmployeeDao{
    HibernateTemplate ht;
    Employee e=new Employee();
    void setHt(HibernateTemplate ht)
    {
        this.ht=ht;
    }

    // for insertion into database

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertValue(Employee e)
    {
        e.setId(1);
        e.setName("james");
        e.setSalary(7000);
        ht.persist(e);
        return "value saved to database";
    }

    //for updation

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateValue(Employee e)
    {
        ht.update(e);
        return "value updated to database";
    }

    //for deletion

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteValue(Employee e)
    {
        ht.delete(e);
        return "value deleted from database";
    }

    // get stored values from d.b

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getValue()
    {
        List<Employee> al=new ArrayList<Employee>();

        al=ht.loadAll(Employee.class);
        return ""+al;

    }

    // to get particular value from d.b

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSpecificValue(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        List<Employee> al=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        al=(List<Employee>) ht.load(Employee.class,id);
        return ""+al;
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver

jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testc

jdbc.db=testc

jdbc.port=5432

jdbc.ip= 127.0.0.1

jdbc.username = postgres

jdbc.password = root

hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

hibernate.show_sql = true

hibernate.format_sql = true
```

Comment: where is the nullpointer exception? which line?

Comment: You really try really hard NOT to use Spring Boot...

Comment: atleast give the logs man.

Comment: How do you expect the `HibernateTemplate` to be created and injected?

Comment: thanks M.Deinum for your valuable comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot then use Spring Boot. Currently you are trying really hard to NOT use Spring Boot.

First instead of you manually configuration a DataSource let Spring Boot do it for you. Remove the `@Bean` for `DataSource` and add `spring.datasource` properties in your `application.properties` (or simply rename the existing ones).

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testc
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Next instead of using plain Hibernate I strongly suggest to start using JPA instead. So remove the definition for the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and `HibernateTransactionManager`. Simply add the following properties to your configuration.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Now basically have an empty configuration class simply remove it. Spring Boot will already component-scan for you, create JPA, enable transactions.

In your controller/dao hybrid (which is a bad thing imho!) instead of the `HibernateTemplate` use the `EntityManager` instead. However I would suggest separating the dao and controller functionality.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class EmployeeDaoJpa implements EmployeeDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    // Method implementations using the EntityManager

}
```

Now in your controller use that dao.

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeDao dao;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeDao dao) {
        this.dao=dao;
    }


    // for insertion into database

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertValue(Employee e) {
        e.setId(1);
        e.setName("james");
        e.setSalary(7000);
        dao.insertvalue(e);
        return "value saved to database";
    }

    //for updation

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateValue(Employee e) {
        dao.updateValue(e);
        return "value updated to database";
    }

    //for deletion

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteValue(Employee e) {
        ht.delete(e);
        return "value deleted from database";
    }

    // get stored values from d.b

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getValue() {
        return ""+dao.findAll();    
    }

    // to get particular value from d.b

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSpecificValue(@PathVariable int id) {
        return ""+dao.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

Another tip don't use `com` as your package first it is to lowlevel and when Spring or your container starts scanning the `com` package it will scan everything in the `com` package. Like everything in jar files starting with `com`. So invent a better package naming.

In the end you now only have your controller, repository class and interface and finally your application class. No more configuration class that is all nicely in your `application.properties`.